# "I got stuck while parsing the function definition:": How to properly define an Elm function?

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I'm experiment/practicing Elm for the first time and am running into difficulty defining a function. The following:

```
isDivisible : Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
isDivisible n x y =
  ((modBy n x) == 0) && ((modBy n y) == 0)

isDivisible 4 4 2
```

Results in:

```
-- PROBLEM IN DEFINITION --------------------------------------- Jump To Problem

I got stuck while parsing the `isDivisible` definition:

5| isDivisible 4 4 2
                    ^
I am not sure what is going wrong exactly, so here is a valid definition (with
an optional type annotation) for reference:

    greet : String -> String
    greet name =
      "Hello " ++ name ++ "!"

Try to use that format!
```

The Elm interpreter that CodeWars uses lets this pass through; it just says that the output is incorrect for some inputs (like `4 4 2`). There are no Google results for `"I got stuck while parsing the * definition:"` (even though the parser is open-source, go figure). This is my first time in a functional language. What's wrong?

Comment: Are you using a REPL or are you trying to write a program?

Comment: Yeah, the issue here is that you are trying to write a function call, but it doesn't make sense for that to be there in the file. You can't just run code at the top level in an Elm file. Either use `elm repl` to test or have a top level `Browser.Program` you can load in a browser.

Comment: "Run code at the top level." What does that mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why your `isDivisible` function takes three numbers, but the syntax error you're seeing does not refer to its definition, but to your call:

```
isDivisible 4 4 2
```

In Elm, all your expressions (like the above) need to live within functions. You cannot simply write them at the top level of your file. They need to be used in a context where Elm knows what to do with them.

Elm programs start executing from the `main` function. The `main` function might return different things depending on what you want to do, but the simplest use case is to return some HTML.

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Html exposing (text)


main =
    text "Hello World"
```

[Run in ellie](https://ellie-app.com/8mzvxRvxdn6a1)

If you compile and open that in your browser, you'll see the text "Hello World" on the screen. Notice we placed our code under the `main` function, instead of writing them in the file directly.

With that in mind, you could do something like the following to show the output of your call:

```
main =
    if isDivisible 4 4 2 then
        text "It is divisible"

    else
        text "It is NOT divisible"
```

[Run in ellie](https://ellie-app.com/8mzBt5dH566a1)

If you just want to see the output of your call in the console instead, you can use the [Debug.log](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Debug#log) function, like this:

```
main =
    let
        _ =
            Debug.log "Is divisible?" (isDivisible 4 4 2)
    in
    text "Hello World"
```

[Run in Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/8mzyK47DhzZa1) (see LOGS)